# FLEX:How to catch 'a href' event

Tags: apache-flex, events, hyperlink

I'm loading data from TextFlow to spark:TextArea. In TextFlow i have 'a href' elements. Problem lies with the address of the 'link' elements. Some of them will go outside of the page (these i will leave without doing anything), other will go to other subpages in my site(these one i have to catch and process in code).

I planned on catching 'clicking on link' event to decide what to do, but i can't do this. I read that by writing

```
<a href="event:page_adress">
```

i could catch the event on link:event in old mx:TextArea, but i cant do this here. I tried to manualy add:

```
addEventListener(TextEvent.Link, functionName)
```

but it doesnt work.
When i change to catching MOUSE_CLICK event i'm catching the event, but cant parse it to get the needed address.

Anybody have idea how to do it? I doesnt have to stick with TextArea, but component have to download content form TextFlow.

PS I noticed that when i added event:page_adress to the 'a href' the link stopped working (that means it probably started throwing events), but i cant catch it...

PS2 TextFlow is imported from external database with

```
TextFlowUtil.importFromXML
```

i tried using in link element, click event but it doesnt work:

```
<a click="myClickHandler(event)">
```

myClickHandler doesnt run after clicking on link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i found answer on this blog: http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2010/10/displaying-html-text-in-labels.html

Bassicly i had to search whole textFlow and in case of founding a Link - adding manually Event to it.

Im posting my code in case that the flexdevtips blog might be down in the future:

```
/**
* Finds the first LinkElement recursively and returns it.
*/          

private function findLinkElement(group:FlowGroupElement):void
{
    var childGroups:Array = [];
    // First check all the child elements of the current group,
    // Also save any children that are FlowGroupElement
    for (var i:int = 0; i < group.numChildren; i++) {
        var element:FlowElement = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (element is LinkElement) 
        {
            linksArray.push(element as LinkElement);
        } else if (element is FlowGroupElement)
        {
            childGroups.push(element);
        }
    }
    // Recursively check the child FlowGroupElements now
    for (i = 0; i < childGroups.length; i++) {
        var childGroup:FlowGroupElement = childGroups[i];
        findLinkElement(childGroup);
    }

  }
```

and i had to use it in my code like this:

```
linksArray = [];

findLinkElement(tt.textFlow);

var iter:int=0;
for (iter = 0 ; iter<linksArray.length ; iter++)
{
                linksArray[iter].addEventListener(FlowElementMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,linkSelect, false, 0, true);
}
```

where tt is my textarea with imported textFlow

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps. I use a html-link like this:

```
<a id="link_1"> Click me </a>
```

The html-file is stored externally. I import the html to a TextFlow using importToFlow and add the Listener in Flex, like this:

```
myTextFlow.addEventListener(FlowElementMouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, showMe);
```

To get the id-property of the link I use:

```
event.flowElement.id
```

Answer (score 0):

just found out how to get the original string:

```
function onClick(event:FlowElementMouseEvent):void 
{
    var link:LinkElement = event.flowElement as LinkElement;
    var text:String = link.href;
}
```

this will return the content of the  tag, so you can parse to get your parameters

> thanks for the post, it helped me a
>   lot. at least i got one step further,
>   i can actually listen to the events.
>
> but i still have a problem, the HTML
>   code i set on my RichEditableText
>   looks like this:
>
> ```
> <a href='event:n," + id + "'>Name</a>
> ```
>
> on Flex3 i could use the
>   TextEvent.LINK get the arguments by
>   its 'text' property, then parse to get
>   the ID data that i need. but now that
>   we are developing in Flex4 i cannot
>   figure out how to do this. after
>   catching the FlowElementMouseEvent i
>   can only get the link text ('Name'),
>   but not the  arguments im sending on
>   the HTML code.
>
> do you have any suggestions on how to
>   do this?