# Listen for hyperlink click in a mx.control.HTML component

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, hyperlink

Is there any way to listen for clicks on hyperlinks in a mx.control.HTML component.
Meaning, if a have a HTML component that has a link

```
<a href='event:SomeText'>A clickable link</a>
```

then can i set up some kind of listener to catch such clicks?

for instance

```
var myHTML:HTML = new HTML();
myHTML.htmlText = "<a href='event:SomeText'>A clickable link</a>";
myHTML.addEventListener(SomeEvent.LINK_CLICK, linkFunction);

function linkFunction(event:SomeEvent):void{
     //do some stuff
}
```

or something like this, i need to execute AS3 code when that link is clicked.

**EDIT**
Or is there any way to access AS3 methods in javascript of the mx:HTML component? Something like this

```
var myHTML:HTML = new HTML();
myHTML.htmlText = "<a href='event:SomeText' onclick='linkFunction()'>A clickable link</a>";

function linkFunction():void{
     //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: <a href='event:SomeText' onclick="">A clickable link</a>

Comment: @ArunKumarM That's not what i meant, please see my edited question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FLEX:How to catch 'a href' event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371740/flexhow-to-catch-a-href-event)

Comment: @akmozo not really, there they are talking about spark:TextArea, but i am asking about mx.controls.HTML

Comment: @M364M4Ncro Yes I know that's about spark:TextArea but I thought that you are flexible to use another component instead of mx:HTML which hasn't any events for that purpose (except `locationChange` maybe) ...

Comment: @akmozo its kind of important that i can use the mx:HTML component, what could i do with `locationChange`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just had an "onclick" attribute.

```
<html>

  <body>
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" onclick="alert('I have been listening');">CLICK ME</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

For example... 
In this code, the link tag first fires off an alert, and only then directs you to the supplied link.

Comment: That's not what i meant, please see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

There is two-way communication between AS and JS. You can check the link below and find out how to notify AS from a JS function/method.

[Adobe Flex Developer Centre](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_javascript.html)

Comment: @M364M4Ncro the link is edited. You can see the second part of the post, the setup and functions directs from JavaScript to ActionScript. With a little tweak, I guess you can achieve what you stated.

Comment: i dont know, the way i see it, it works when makng a web aplication, not sure if it will work in my case, and i have given up on the mx:HTML control and instead use the Text control which can listen for TextEvent.LINK